# How to tell if someone as turned off Facebook chat for you? Chat bar and "last online"

Tags: facebook-messenger

If someone has turned off Facebook chat for you, will they appear in the chat bar if you search by their name or not at all? There's this person I used to check for the "last online time", usually he's online everyday, and I haven't had that information for over a week now. Could that mean that he has turned off the chat for me?